# How can I optimize aggregations of cartesian pairs between two list columns across an entire dataframe within PySpark at scale?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, query-optimization

Hello World, (felt fitting as this is my first question on stackoverflow)

I'm hoping to get some advice on how to optimize the aggregation of what I'll describe as 'cartesian' pairs between two columns in a dataframe that both contain lists of longs.

I've provided the code for a small scale example that works exactly as expected to help articulate what I am trying to achieve in the hopes that it better articulates the problem. The key steps are:

1. Calculate the 'cartesian' pairs between col(A) and col(B) (using UDF udf_product())
2. Collate all the 'cartesian' pairs across all rows in the dataframe into a single row (using collect_set() aggregation)
3. Flatten the collated result from a 3 level array to a 2 level array for ease of handling downstream (using UDF udf_flatten3Dto2DList())

(i.e. convert collated results from

[       [ [pair1 from row1], ... , [pairN from row 2] ], [  [pair1 from row2], ... , [pairN from row2]  ], ... , [  [pair1 from rowM], ... , [pairN from rowM]  ]       ]

to

[   [pair1 from row1], ... , [pairN from row 2], [pair1 from row2], ... , [pairN from row2], ... , [pair1 from rowM], ... , [pairN from rowM]

essentially removing list separation based on rows)

4. Collect() the collated list of all pairs outside of the dataframe structure (note I am only collect()-ing a single row due to the use of an aggregated select() transformation prior to the collect(), which should hopefully mean this is not computationally costly at all... Please correct me if I am wrong here...)
5. Convert pairs from list format to tuple format to enable su to leverage the Counter() function
6. Use Counter() function to finally arrive at total count for each col(A) x col(B) cartesian pair appearing across the entire dataframe

**Below is my small scale example, setting the control parameters such that the computation time is low to show that the logic works.**

```
### Import relevant modules / functions
import random
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.storagelevel import StorageLevel
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import * 
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from collections import Counter ## used for dictionary work
from itertools import product ## product('AB', 'xyz') == 'Ax' 'Ay' 'Az' 'Bx' 'By' 'Bz'

### Define UDFs to calculate all col(A) and col(B) 'dot product' pairings
udf_flatten3Dto2DList = udf(lambda x: [item for list in x for item in list], ArrayType(ArrayType(LongType())))
def product_lists(x, y):
  return [[x for x in pair] for pair in product(x, y)]
udf_product = udf(product_lists, ArrayType(ArrayType(LongType())))

############ EXAMPLE THAT WORKS AS EXPECTED ################
### Define parameters to control scale of problem
pair_index_options = 3
num_rows = 10

### Create dummy dataframe
a = spark.createDataFrame([(1, [random.randrange(1,pair_index_options + 1, random.randrange(1,pair_index_options + 1)], [random.randrange(1,pair_index_options + 1), random.randrange(1,pair_index_options + 1)]) for i in range(num_rows)], ['ID', 'A', 'B'])
a.show()

>>> OUTPUT:
+---+------+------+
| ID|     A|     B|
+---+------+------+
|  1|[2, 2]|[3, 3]|
|  1|[2, 3]|[1, 2]|
|  1|[1, 2]|[2, 1]|
|  1|[1, 3]|[2, 1]|
|  1|[2, 1]|[1, 1]|
|  1|[3, 1]|[2, 1]|
|  1|[3, 1]|[2, 3]|
|  1|[1, 1]|[1, 1]|
|  1|[1, 1]|[3, 1]|
|  1|[2, 2]|[2, 1]|
+---+------+------+


pair_lists = a.withColumn('product', udf_product('A','B'))
              .select(f.collect_list('product').alias('product'))
              .withColumn('product_pairs', udf_flatten3Dto2DList('product'))
              .collect()[0]['product_pairs']
print(pair_lists)

>>> OUTPUT:
[[1, 2], [1, 1], [2, 2], [2, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 1], [3, 2], [3, 1], [1, 3], [1, 1], [1, 3], [1, 1], [2, 1], [2, 2], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 2], [3, 3], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 1], [2, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1], [2, 2], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 1], [2, 3], [2, 3], [2, 3], [2, 3], [3, 2], [3, 1], [1, 2], [1, 1]]

### Convert lists to tuples to enable creation of a counter Dictionary (lists are not 'keyable' as they are not immutable)
pair_tuples = [tuple(pair) for pair in pair_lists]
dict_Counter = Counter(pair_tuples)
print(dict_Counter)

>>> OUTPUT:
Counter({(1, 1): 11, (2, 1): 6, (1, 2): 4, (2, 2): 4, (3, 2): 4, (2, 3): 4, (3, 1): 3, (1, 3): 3, (3, 3): 1})
```

**Below is my 'real world' example, adjusting the control parameters to scale the problem up to one that is more representative of the scale of my actual problem (causing what I understood to be some sort of out of memory error).**

```
############ EXAMPLE THAT CRASHES ################
pair_index_options = 200 ## Scale such that there are approximately 40,000 pair combinations
num_pairs = int(1e8) ### Scale such that there are approximately 100,000,000 rows to process

a = spark.createDataFrame([(1, [random.randrange(1,pair_index_options + 1), random.randrange(1,pair_index_options + 1)], [random.randrange(1,pair_index_options + 1), random.randrange(1,pair_index_options + 1)]) for i in range(num_pairs)], ['ID', 'A', 'B'])
a.show()
pair_lists = a.withColumn('product', udf_product('A', 'B')).select(f.collect_list('product').alias('product')).withColumn('product_pairs', udf_flatten3Dto2DList('product')).collect()[0]['product_pairs']
print(pair_lists)
print("")
pair_tuples = [tuple(pair) for pair in pair_lists]
dict_Counter = Counter(pair_tuples)
print(dict_Counter)
```

**Below is the error that is produced in Databricks when running the 'real world' example.**

My limited knowledge on interpreting the error logs has me thinking that the crux of the issue relates to this piece of output "Cannot grow BufferHolder by size 176 because the size after growing exceeds size limitation 2147483632", which based on some google searching has to do with memory issues but I'm not sure how to resolve this.

> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
>   Task 0 in stage 77.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task
>   0.3 in stage 77.0 (TID 1986, 10.139.64.11, executor 0): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot grow BufferHolder by size
>   176 because the size after growing exceeds size limitation 2147483632
>
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>        19 a = spark.createDataFrame([(1, [1, 2], [3, 4]) for i in range(num_pairs)], ['ID', 'A', 'B'])
>        20 a.show()
>   ---> 21 pair_lists = a.withColumn('product', udf_product('A', 'B')).select(f.collect_list('product').alias('product')).withColumn('product_pairs',
>   udf_flatten3Dto2DList('product')).collect()[0]['product_pairs']
>        22 print(pair_lists)
>        23 print("")
>
> /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in collect(self)
>       550         # Default path used in OSS Spark / for non-DF-ACL clusters:
>       551         with SCCallSiteSync(self._sc) as css:
>   --> 552             sock_info = self._jdf.collectToPython()
>       553         return list(_load_from_socket(sock_info, BatchedSerializer(PickleSerializer())))
>       554
>
> /databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py
>   in **call**(self, *args)    1255         answer =
>   self.gateway_client.send_command(command)    1256         return_value
>   = get_return_value(
>   -> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)    1258     1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:
>
> /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
>        61     def deco(*a, **kw):
>        62         try:
>   ---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
>        64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
>        65             s = e.java_exception.toString()
>
> /databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in
>   get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
>       326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
>       327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
>   --> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
>       329             else:
>       330                 raise Py4JError(
>
> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o12878.collectToPython.
>   : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
>   Task 0 in stage 77.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task
>   0.3 in stage 77.0 (TID 1986, 10.139.64.11, executor 0): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot grow BufferHolder by size
>   176 because the size after growing exceeds size limitation 2147483632
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.BufferHolder.grow(BufferHolder.java:71)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.UnsafeWriter.grow(UnsafeWriter.java:62)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.UnsafeWriter.write(UnsafeWriter.java:160)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.AggregationIterator$$anonfun$generateResultProjection$1.apply(AggregationIterator.scala:235)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.AggregationIterator$$anonfun$generateResultProjection$1.apply(AggregationIterator.scala:224)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.ObjectAggregationIterator.next(ObjectAggregationIterator.scala:86)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.ObjectAggregationIterator.next(ObjectAggregationIterator.scala:33)
>     at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)  at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)   at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)   at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.takeDestructively(Iterator.scala:1074)
>     at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.go(Iterator.scala:1089)
>     at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.fill(Iterator.scala:1126)
>     at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:1130)
>     at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)   at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)   at
>   scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)    at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:368)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$2.writeIteratorToStream(PythonUDFRunner.scala:50)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply(PythonRunner.scala:430)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:2136)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:236)
>
> Driver stacktrace:    at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2362)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:2350)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:2349)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
>     at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2349)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1102)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1102)
>     at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1102)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2582)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2529)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2517)
>     at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:897)
>     at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2280)    at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2378)     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector.runSparkJobs(Collector.scala:245)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector.collect(Collector.scala:280)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector$.collect(Collector.scala:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector$.collect(Collector.scala:86)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ResultCacheManager.getOrComputeResult(ResultCacheManager.scala:508)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ResultCacheManager.getOrComputeResult(ResultCacheManager.scala:480)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollectResult(SparkPlan.scala:325)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$50.apply(Dataset.scala:3358)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$50.apply(Dataset.scala:3357)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$54.apply(Dataset.scala:3492)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$54.apply(Dataset.scala:3487)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:113)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:242)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:99)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:172)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$withAction(Dataset.scala:3487)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectToPython(Dataset.scala:3357)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)  at
>   py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:380)    at
>   py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:295)     at
>   py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
>     at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)   at
>   py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:251)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot grow BufferHolder by size
>   176 because the size after growing exceeds size limitation 2147483632
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.BufferHolder.grow(BufferHolder.java:71)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.UnsafeWriter.grow(UnsafeWriter.java:62)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.UnsafeWriter.write(UnsafeWriter.java:160)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.AggregationIterator$$anonfun$generateResultProjection$1.apply(AggregationIterator.scala:235)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.AggregationIterator$$anonfun$generateResultProjection$1.apply(AggregationIterator.scala:224)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.ObjectAggregationIterator.next(ObjectAggregationIterator.scala:86)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.ObjectAggregationIterator.next(ObjectAggregationIterator.scala:33)
>     at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)  at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)   at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)   at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.takeDestructively(Iterator.scala:1074)
>     at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.go(Iterator.scala:1089)
>     at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.fill(Iterator.scala:1126)
>     at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:1130)
>     at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)   at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)   at
>   scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)    at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:368)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$2.writeIteratorToStream(PythonUDFRunner.scala:50)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply(PythonRunner.scala:430)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:2136)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:236)

**My question, I guess, has two parts:**

1. Is there a better approach to arriving at the total count of pairs existing within the starting dataframe based on col(A) and col(B)?
2. If not (highly unlikely ;)), is there a way to optimize my approach above such that I avoid the memory error?

Thanks in advance!

David

Comment: I  notice no other answer is forthcoming. I think my answer is very correct.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, Cartesian Join / Cross Product are with large datasets the "large, large table join". Something Spark is not so good at..

If you do not have enough RAM and then enough disk for spillage, it will not work and get OOM. Partition size is bigger now, but in the end it is a nightmare of traffic between executors.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts, the bluephantom. Perhaps a poor choice of words on my part, but I dont believe I'm doing a cartesian join of dataframes. I'm calculating all combinations between two list items in two different columns within the dataframe.  Do you still believe this would be something Spark doesnt process well?

Comment: forgot to @ you so just recommenting

Comment: Amounts to the same thing. OOM and in your case 2GB error. rows or cols, same space.